# Spring Boot project not autowiring the services in another spring mvc project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two Spring boot and spring mvc project. I want to get the service of the spring mvc project. Spring boot project work as the client. I added spring mvc project name as a dependecy on the pom.xml in spring boot project. Then I can call the method of the spring mvc project but it's inside services are not autowired.

following service are null when I look them at the debugg time.

```
@Autowired
    PriceResultService priceResultService; --null

    @Autowired
    PriceFactorService priceFactorService; --null

    @Autowired
    OptionalExtrasService optionalExtrasService; --null

    @Autowired
    BaseCommonRulesService baseCommonRulesService; --null

    @Autowired
    BasePartyTypeRulesService basePartyTypeRulesService; --null

    @Autowired
    MedicalCommonRulesService medicalCommonRulesService; --null

    @Autowired
    OptionalExtraRulesService optionalExtraRulesService; --null

    @Autowired
    CoverLimitRulesService coverLimitRulesService; --null
```

how to solve that,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `mvc` module to scan classpath.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {YourSpringBootApplication.class, YourMVCClassInRootPackage.class})
public class YourSpringBootApplication {

}
```

Suppose your MVC module look like:

```
/com/path/
   DummyBean.class
/com/path/child1/
   AnotherBean.class
   AnotherBeanX.class
   AnotherBeanY.class
/com/path/child2
   AnotherBean2.class
   AnotherBeanZ.class
```

Then you choose `YourMVCClassInRootPackage` is `DummyBean`.

If your MVC module look like:

```
/com/path/child1/
   AnotherBean.class
   AnotherBeanX.class
   AnotherBeanY.class
/com/path/child2
   AnotherBean2.class
   AnotherBeanZ.class
```

No class in the top most package so you either create a `DummyBean.java` in the top package (like `/com/path/DummyBean`) or include all `AnotherBean`, `AnotherBean2` to scan classpath. **(Choose one class for each package)**

Comment: YourSpringBootApplication class means my main class of the spring boot project?

Comment: Yes. For YourMVCClassInRootPackage you have to choose the bean class which is in root package of your Mvc module

Comment: How do I identifiy the bean classes in the spring mvc project.

Comment: I'm sorry I have not right  to do that. Anyway suppose if I add any class name of the Repository or Service top of the package stucture is it ok?

Comment: Ya, but one class for each top package is enough

Comment: One reminder: if your mvc module has similar package name to the boot module then the easiest way is to move the Application class to the top most package

Comment: I'm glad it helped